# Xamarin Android GCM Client does not work

Tags: android, azure, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android

I have set up the GCM Client according to the example in [the Xamarin component store](https://components.xamarin.com/view/gcmclient/). Furthermore I have followed the tutorial on [Notification Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-notification-hubs-android-get-started/).
I run my test on the Android 4.4.2 Emulator with Google API 19 and on various android devices (4.4, 5.1). I am working with the latest version of Xamarin.

In the emulator the PushHandlerService.OnRegistered is called and I can register the device token in the notification hub. However, the PushHandlerService.OnMessage method is not called when I send a message.

On real devices, not even the PushHandlerService.OnRegistered is called.

I have tried to send the message via notification hub and directly via the GCM service (HTTP Post). Both calls to the services succeed, but the message does not arrive in my app. I have tried notification messages with notification and/or data payload while the app is active or closed. I added my google account to the emulator. I have ensured that my google project number and package name are correct (google developer console corresponds to app).

How can I investigate my issue further? 
Is there a possibility to see the delivery log in GCM? 
Is there a way to see if the notification message at least arrives in my emulator's operating system? 
What can go wrong so that my emulator receives a registration ID, but not the real device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with the new GCM API according to the Xamarin tutorial: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/

Furthermore I unblocked the GCM ports on our firewall: :  5228, 5229, 5230